# cannot read property 'then' of undefined on auto complete

Tags: angularjs

I get an error saying :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined* on angularjs
```

controller :

```
function querySearch (query) {
    $http ({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'autocomplete/?search=' + query
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data
        })
}
```

html file:

```
<md-autocomplete md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-selected-item="row.items" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-require-match="">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.category}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Proper code formatting, and removed redundant Tag name from title.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not injecting $http in your controller, do:

```
.controller($scope, $http){ /* your code */ }
```

Also you need to populate some array first `$scope.items = response.data;`, before you do `ng-repeat` or at least return a promise `return $http().then()`, because otherwise your data will not bind to ng-repeat as it's asynchronous

Comment: I have injected $http in my controller.
can you explain `return $http().then()`?

Comment: you are not returning `response.data` anywhere unless you return a promise and resolve it with `then` (i.e. `return $http(url).then((res)=>{return res.data})`) by later populating some $scope variable that you will use in your `ng-repeat`, alternatively just make a list and populate in in `querySearch` function right away without returning anything. Usually you would have some service/factory that resolve any logic, but a controller can do it just fine, but then there is no point in returning values unlike for a service case